# What is the consequence of skipping tests on a maven build?

Tags: maven, testing, build, installation, mahout

Let's say I install a tool like mahout via maven using

```
mvn install
```

Sometimes this will result in BUILD FAILURE. However, by adding -DskipTests the build is successful. What is the consequence of doing this to install the package? Is it ok to use the files maven has downloaded?

Comment: normally it is due to failure of any of the test case. Can specify the error due to which build failure occurred ?

Comment: I thought I'd just make a new question about that, but it's here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351177/maven-build-failure-when-installing-mahout-on-ubuntu

If you have any idea what to do that would be great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your maven build fails when tests are run but succeeds when you skip tests, then one or more of your tests are failing.

The consequence of installing the package from a build that skipped tests depends on how good your tests are.

If your tests are extensive, then a failure indicates something is not behaving as expected. Deploying that code would be risky as it would be very likely to fail in production.

If your tests are not very good then deploying code that passes or fails them is equally risky as you don't have a good indicator as to how well the code performs.

The files maven downloads are the dependencies declared in your project and in the other dependencies. These are third party packages that you can usually assume work correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't create any of these tests, I'm just trying to install software from apache.

I am using subversion to check out the mahout code from apache's repository and then using maven to install mahout. It worked on my Ubuntu machine, I am now testing to see if I can get it to work on an Ubuntu VM running on a Windows 7 host. 

Could it be down to the VM environment? To be honest I think it should still work just fine even if it is a virtual machine.

It's quite painful because the build/testing process is very lengthy!